# How do I pass json in the url of a REST request?

Tags: json, rest

I am creating a kafka broker in a cluster by sending a request to the url. According to the api it says that I can add additional options to my broker in the form `/api/broker/<cli command>?broker={broker-expr}&<setting>=<value>`, however the setting that I need to set has json as its value. How would I do this?

I've tried quite a few different ways of writing it at none of them work. The json value is meant to be

```
{
    "period":"10s"
}
```

I've tried

- `/api/broker/remove?broker=0&stickiness={"period":"10s"}`
- `/api/broker/remove?broker=8&stickiness={period:10s}`
- `/api/broker/remove?broker=8&stickiness="{period:10s}"`

Update:
I've tried encoding the url but it still doesn't work. Everything is decoded except for the `:`.

The string I enter for the json: `%7B%22period%22%3A%22600s%22%7D`

This is what it ends up as after I send it.
[image]

How do I encode a `:` ?

Comment: why in the query, why not in the body?
Also did you know you could use http://restsharp.org/ for all your REST purposes?

Comment: Because that's what their REST api dictates

Comment: But there is always a body with the REST request. AFAIK, this is the bad way of executing in query itself. otherwise you would have always to encode and then decode later.

Comment: There is no body when there is a get request. I don't understand what you're confused about, even if it's a dumb way of doing things it's still what the API says I have to use.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first option you suggested is correct JSON. However, the JSON will need to be encoded.

Encoding just the JSON part results in %7B%22period%22%3A%2210s%22%7D

Check out the following site for more on URL encoding
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: It can't seem to decode my colon, every site/tool I use encodes it as %3A but when I try to send the request it's the only bit that isn't decoded properly.